# Hibernate 5 seems to use different connection pools for session with and without transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I am using hibernate 5.6 and I am observing an odd effect I don't Understand. For development I configured c3p0 with maximum number of connections set to 1, in order to detect missing close of sessions.

To test this, I added a Thread.sleep(15000) call just before I close each session, and as expected my website crawls to 1 request each 15 seconds, because each new page can't be shown, until the previous session was closed. So far so good.

But then something odd happens. I have a Servlet, which use the session object without calling beginTransaction() on the session.

If I insert a sleep(30000) call in this servlet after using the session, and just before I close the session the rest of my website does not hang. But If i start a new request to this servlet, this second request, will wait until the first request finishes.

So it is like hibernate does have 2 session pools. One for sessions which use transactions, and one for sessions which don't use transactions. Is this true, and described in the documentation?

My first thought was obviously, that I create 2 different sessionFactories, but logging shows the session factory is the same for all my servlets. And If i modify the servlet to start with a call to beginTransaction() it the rest of the site hangs until the session is closed.

I am using Apache Tomcat and Hibernate, but I don't use Spring, and I have created the session factory object myself.

The relevant from my hibernate.cfg.xml file is:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate will acquire the JDBC connection as late as possible. When you use `beginTransaction`, it has to acquire the connection.
Simply creating a session does not immediately create a JDBC connection though, so a concurrent request that doesn't interact with the session in any way won't block.

Comment: But I don't just create the session. I use it to do a select query, before I call sleep.

Comment: Without seeing the code that your transactions are running, it's impossible for me to figure out what is happening.